# Pandas merge over missing values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a case,

```
C       +---+---+
        | a | b |
        +---+---+
      1 |NA |foo|
        +---+---+
      2 |bar|foo|
        +---+---+

D       +---+---+
        | x | y |
        +---+---+
      1 |ba |foo|
        +---+---+
      2 |bar|foo|
        +---+---+

Output  +---+---+
        | a | x |
        +---+---+
      1 |NA |ba |
        +---+---+
      2 |NA |bar|
        +---+---+
      3 |bar|bar|
        +---+---+
```

merge on both keys 'a' and 'x' will result in a data frame containing only index 2. However, I am looking for a way to get the `a` having `NA` in df C should not be considered for merging.
So, the final result will have 3 rows. Df C index 1 will match both indexes 1 and 2 of df D.

What could be the possible workaround?

Comment: Sorry can't you drop the `NaN` values prior to merging? `C.dropna().merge(D.dropna())` or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, there was something else, I forgot to mention.